# How to add a legend to a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend, heatmap

I am using a small variation of this [really nice code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76442369/1473517) to plot a heatmap.

```
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

np.random.seed(7)
A = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(20,20))
mask_array = np.zeros((20, 20), dtype=bool)
mask_array[:, :5] = True
# cmap = matplotlib.colormaps["viridis"]
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis').copy()


# Set the under color to white
cmap.set_under("white")

# Set the over color to white
cmap.set_over("black")

# Set the background color

g = sns.heatmap(A, vmin=10, vmax=90, cmap=cmap, mask=mask_array)
# Set color of masked region
g.set_facecolor('lightgrey')

cbar_ax = g.figure.axes[-1]

for spine in cbar_ax.spines.values():
    spine.set(visible=True)
    
special_data = np.ma.masked_where(A==20, A)
sns.heatmap(special_data, cmap=ListedColormap((1.0000, 0.2716, 0.0000)), 
            mask=(special_data != 1), cbar=False)
```

The result looks like:

[image: heatmap]

The squares that had the value 20 and so are now colored with RGB (1.0000, 0.2716, 0.0000) indicate that the experiment was broken. I would like to add a legend that has a square of that color and the word "broken" next to it. It will have to be outside the heatmap so as not to obscure it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your own rectangle with the color you want and feed it into the legend method. If you want to move the legend around then you can use the `loc` and `bbox_to_anchor` arguments- see the legend guide for more info on these https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

# ...

rect = Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=(1.0000, 0.2716, 0.0000))
g.legend(handles=[rect], labels=['Broken'], loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image]

Inserting all of the code you already have...

```py
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
from matplotlib.pyplot import show
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

np.random.seed(7)
A = np.random.randint(0,100, size=(20,20))
mask_array = np.zeros((20, 20), dtype=bool)
mask_array[:, :5] = True
# cmap = matplotlib.colormaps["viridis"]
cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis').copy()


# Set the under color to white
cmap.set_under("white")

# Set the over color to white
cmap.set_over("black")

# Set the background color

g = sns.heatmap(A, vmin=10, vmax=90, cmap=cmap, mask=mask_array)
# Set color of masked region
g.set_facecolor('lightgrey')

cbar_ax = g.figure.axes[-1]

for spine in cbar_ax.spines.values():
    spine.set(visible=True)

special_data = np.ma.masked_where(A==20, A)
sns.heatmap(special_data, cmap=ListedColormap((1.0000, 0.2716, 0.0000)),
            mask=(special_data != 1), cbar=False, ax=g)

rect = Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color=(1.0000, 0.2716, 0.0000))
g.legend(handles=[rect], labels=['Broken'], loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

show()
```